# How to read internal nodes of embedded schema using core service factory java?

Tags: schema, embedded-items

[image]

I am able to read xml name, description and type (In picture,callToAction, Calls To Action, Embedded Schema respectively). How to read internal node of embedded schema(In picture,Link_ES) using core service factory java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try in the following way. Not sure if i got you correctly, but seems you want to parse the schema filed nodes, not from any component with value in the fields.

Load Schema Details first,

```
SchemaFieldsData schemaFieldsData = _coreServiceClient.ReadSchemaFields(schemaId, false, null);
```

Then, search for the embedded fields using the following:

```
public void GetEmbeddedFields(SchemaFieldsData schemaFields)
{
    foreach (ItemFieldDefinitionData field in schemaFields.Fields)
    {
        if (field.GetType() == typeof(EmbeddedSchemaFieldDefinitionData))
        {
            // check if this field contains more embedded fields

        }
    }
```

}

You can refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509653/recursive-function-to-going-through-each-embedded-schema-field-in-a-schema-to-re) for more information. Thanks.

Comment: Great, can you up vote and mark it as answer so that others can refer to the same as useful for similar kind of issues.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to read the available fields inside of the embedded schema.

In that case, from the parent Schema you will only get tcm-id of the Embedded Schema, which you will have to use with Core Service to get the details of the available fields in the Embedded Schema.

-Kunal

Comment: Hey Kunal, Thanks for your response.Could you please elaborate? I mean there is a method to read the tcm id of parent schema,how can we get the tcm id of embedded schema?